# Help me prevent horizontal scroller from appearing around relative positioned page

Tags: css

I'm setting up http://www.streetofwalls.com

You'll see that there is an irritating gap appearing next to the relatively positioned #wrapper (which contains the whole page). It causes the whole page to scroll about an inch to the right (for no apparent reason). I can remove the gap by changing the position property, but then the page doesn't center. I'm stumped about why this is happening. Help!

Comment: set the width of the facebook like button to 75 you dont need it to be 450

Comment: I just saw this after responding below. You were exactly right!

Comment: gold to help! give me a correct answer. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the width of the facebook like button to 75 you don't need it to be 450

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion to try would be instead of having the div#wrapper be position relative, instead trying wrapper the header elements within a `<header>  ...   </header>` or simply a div, and then applying the `position: relative;` to that instead.  Because that div will be 100% of it's parent (the wrapper - that is 860px)

Just a suggestion.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It turned out that there were elements inside my header that were invisible, but extending outside of the width of the header div. Basically this: